# Minitube removal

Tags: software-installation, uninstall, minitube

I tried to install minitube using the commands in noobslab. I couldn't do it because of the problem in obtaining API key. Now, I want to get rid of every modification done by the following commands in my computer.

The commands are written below:-

```
wget -O minitube.sh http://drive.noobslab.com/data/apps/minitube/minitube.sh
chmod +x minitube.sh
source ./minitube.sh
```

Here is list of errors I get on using the command `sudo make install` after changing the directory.

```
root@dasaswag:~/minitube-master# sudo make uninstall 
rm -f "/usr/bin/minitube"
rmdir /usr/bin/ 
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/bin/': Directory not empty
Makefile:1700: recipe for target 'uninstall_target' failed
make: [uninstall_target] Error 1 (ignored)
rm -f -r /usr/share/minitube/locale
rmdir /usr/share/minitube/ 
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/share/minitube/': No such file or directory
Makefile:1710: recipe for target 'uninstall_translations' failed
make: [uninstall_translations] Error 1 (ignored)
rm -f -r /usr/share/applications/minitube.desktop
rmdir /usr/share/applications/ 
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/share/applications/': Directory not empty
Makefile:1720: recipe for target 'uninstall_desktop' failed
make: [uninstall_desktop] Error 1 (ignored)
rm -f -r /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/minitube.svg
rmdir /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/ 
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/': Directory not empty
Makefile:1730: recipe for target 'uninstall_iconsvg' failed
make: [uninstall_iconsvg] Error 1 (ignored)
rm -f -r /usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/minitube.png
rmdir /usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/ 
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/': Directory not empty
Makefile:1740: recipe for target 'uninstall_icon16' failed
make: [uninstall_icon16] Error 1 (ignored)
rm -f -r /usr/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/apps/minitube.png
rmdir /usr/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/apps/ 
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/apps/': Directory not empty
Makefile:1750: recipe for target 'uninstall_icon22' failed
make: [uninstall_icon22] Error 1 (ignored)
rm -f -r /usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/minitube.png
rmdir /usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/ 
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/': Directory not empty
Makefile:1760: recipe for target 'uninstall_icon32' failed
make: [uninstall_icon32] Error 1 (ignored)
rm -f -r /usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/minitube.png
rmdir /usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/ 
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/': Directory not empty
Makefile:1770: recipe for target 'uninstall_icon48' failed
make: [uninstall_icon48] Error 1 (ignored)
rm -f -r /usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps/minitube.png
rmdir /usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps/ 
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps/': Directory not empty
Makefile:1780: recipe for target 'uninstall_icon64' failed
make: [uninstall_icon64] Error 1 (ignored)
rm -f -r /usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/minitube.png
rmdir /usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/ 
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/': Directory not empty
Makefile:1790: recipe for target 'uninstall_icon128' failed
make: [uninstall_icon128] Error 1 (ignored)
rm -f -r /usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/minitube.png
rmdir /usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/ 
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/': Directory not empty
Makefile:1800: recipe for target 'uninstall_icon256' failed
make: [uninstall_icon256] Error 1 (ignored)
rm -f -r /usr/share/icons/hicolor/512x512/apps/minitube.png
rmdir /usr/share/icons/hicolor/512x512/apps/ 
rmdir: failed to remove '/usr/share/icons/hicolor/512x512/apps/': Directory not empty
Makefile:1810: recipe for target 'uninstall_icon512' failed
make: [uninstall_icon512] Error 1 (ignored)
root@dasaswag:~/minitube-master# ./source minitube.sh 
bash: ./source: No such file or directory
root@dasaswag:~/minitube-master#
```

Comment: Where did the installation stop? There would have been an error message....

Comment: I had some problem getting the correct API code and then it installation was aborted.

Comment: @andrew.46 This was the error message "Error in the application, Exiting".  It doesn't give much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script adds:

1. A set of dependencies
2. The source code for minitube

Removal of both of these can be accomplished with some care.

**1. Dependencies**

The script downloads dependencies with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential qt4-dev-tools libphonon-dev \
libqt4-sql-sqlite phonon-backend-gstreamer phonon-backend-gstreamer
```

But you will have found that each of these dependencies has dragged in many more related files. As well some of these files might be used by other applications on your system.

However you could try removing the files above by simply replacing `sudo apt-get install` with `sudo apt-get remove` in the above code block.

My advice: *leave the dependencies in place*, this is the safe option...

**2. Source Code**

The script downloads the source code as a file called `master.zip` and decompresses it to a directory named `minitube-master`. From there the code is compiled and installed. These files should be: `~/master.zip` and `~/minitube-master`.

So to remove the files you can try these following commands in sequence:

```
cd ~/minitube-master
sudo make uninstall
cd
rm -rf ~/minitube-master
rm ~/master.zip
```

And then hopefully all will be well.

Comment: I did not touch the dependencies, like you said. But I was getting a bunch of errors on typing the command `sudo make uninstall`. I think it's because minitube wasn't installed.

Comment: @EmadArshadAlam Indeed, I suspect this is the case. So now if you are keen to use minitube you could perhaps simply try from the Repositories: `sudo apt-get install minitube` or download the appropriate deb file from the minitube website...

Comment: What happened then? What do you think?

Comment: I updated my question with the list of errors that were shown.

Comment: @EmadArshadAlam When I installed minitube on Xenial the dependencies were installed ok and the archive was downloaded, extracted and the compile started. I also could not make head nor tail of the Google API thing and the susequent compile failed. Thus on my own system I simple deleted the extracted archive and the archive itself. This has probably happened on your system as well....

Comment: I guess, you are right. Nothing was installed, I'll just uninstall the folders manually.